# Is it possible to have a Func<bool> as a while condition

Tags: c#, loops, lambda

Good evening,

I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
while(true)
{
   MyEnum currentValue = GetMyEnumValueFromDB();
   if(currentValue == MyEnum.BreakIfYouGetThis)
      break;
   else if(currentValue == MyEnum.AlsoBreakIfYouGetThis)
      break;
   else
      //Do some computing
}
```

But instead of having a while(true) loop, I'd want to encapsulate the conditional logic in a Func and execute it like this:

```
while(new Func<bool>(/* what goes here? */))
{
   //Do some computing
}
```

In my case at least, it would look much cleaner, but i'm not sure how to do it (kinda new at Func/Action..).

**EDIT** hope this clarifies:
It could also be done like this:

```
while(GetMyEnumValueFromDB() != MyEnum.BreakIfYouGetThis && 
      GetMyEnumValueFromDB() != MyEnum.AlsoBreakIfYouGetThis)
{
   //Do some computing
}
```

But that's 2 call to the database...

Thanks =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you *could* have:

```
Func<bool> condition = ...;

while (condition())
{
}
```

Is that what you're thinking of? It's not really clear...

EDIT: In the example you've given, I'd use something like:

```
private static readonly MyEnum[] BreakEnumValues = { 
    MyEnum.BreakIfYouGetThis,
    MyEnum.AlsoBreakIfYouGetThis
};

...

while (!BreakEnumValues.Contains(GetMyEnumValueFromDB()))
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```
private static bool ShouldBreak(MyEnum enumFromDatabase)
{
    return enumFromDatabase == MyEnum.BreakIfYouGetThis ||
           enumFromDatabase == MyEnum.AlsoBreakIfYouGetThis;
}

...

while (!ShouldBreak(GetMyEnumValueFromDB))
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT: To counter KeithS's answer, this is entirely valid:

```
while (new Func<bool>(() => {
    Console.WriteLine("Evaluating...");
    return true;
})()) {
    Console.WriteLine("In loop");
    count++;
    if (count == 5)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

It's horrible, but it's valid. (It can be made slightly less horrid by explicitly calling `Invoke`, but it's still not nice.)

Comment: I'd like to put the whole Func<bool> creation and calculation withing the while parenthesis.

Comment: @Baboon: Why? That will create a new delegate on each iteration - I can't see what benefit that has over just putting the condition in *without* using a delegate. You *claim* something would look cleaner, but it's not at all clear why.

Comment: I like this answer, but I'd also question why Baboon would need to create a Func to represent his condition. The expression within the Func could, if locally-scoped, be evaluated directly. The major utility of a Func in this instance would be to easily swap them out, and in that case you WANT the variable, so you can change the delegate assigned to it.

Comment: The function dealing with this loop is already awfully complicated, and this condition is trivial, I'd just like that loop to be more concise, and I'm interested in using funcs. Besides, creating such a tiny Func would harm performance?

Comment: @Baboon: Why would you *assume* that using a `Func` is going to make it more concise? You seem to have chosen a solution and assumed it's going to help, but with no real evidence for this...

Comment: @Baboon:  You're worried about performance but still have a database call in a while loop???

Comment: @Baboon: Why not just create a new method that encapsulates your logic, returning a `bool`, and call that in your `while` condition?

Comment: I was thinking of Func<bool> just because it would allow me to store a local variable from which i'd read twice and assert if the content of the loop can still be executed or not. I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: @Baboon: But how do you expect that to be better than putting the whole condition within the parenthesis *without* creating a `Func<bool>`? That's what I still don't understand...

Comment: If i don't use a Func<bool>, how can i store the value returned by the db in order to check it twice? (see my edited question).

Comment: @Baboon: Well you *can* do it via side-effects - but personally I'd try to write something so that I could evaluate it all via one call. If this is *really* enums, it's easy - but it's not clear whether that example is just a simplified version. It sounds like a separate method would really be handy...

Comment: Maybe it could be solved by writing a recursive method that takes a Func<bool> and an Action as parameters?

Comment: @Baboon: I really think you're overthinking this - it's as if you've decided that delegates *are* going to give you a more concise way of doing things, and you're coming up with more and more complicated approaches to achieve that aim.

Comment: Yes, i am overthinking this. But even if just for educational purpose, I still don't know how it could be done.

Comment: @JonSkeet I really appreciate the effort, but KeithS actually solved the problem (by saying it can't be done, unfortunately).

Comment: @Baboon: He hasn't, because he's wrong... I've commented on his answer, and edited my answer to give an example of what you could be really *shouldn't* do.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that, but if you don't have a compelling reason to do so (like you're passing the condition function in as a parameter), I'd just wrap your logic in a function and call it directly:

```
while(KeepGoing())
{
    //Do stuff
}

bool KeepGoing()
{
    // Check conditions for continuing
    var value = GetMyEnumValueFromDB();
    return value != MyEnum.BreakIfYouGetThis && value != MyEnum.AlsoBreakIfYouGetThis;
}
```

Comment: The condition is used only in this very place, and nowhere else. It doesn't justify adding a function IMO.

Comment: Yet you want to add a delegate instead? That only makes sense if you want to swap out the condition function, and it's slower than using a function, and both are equally clear.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a database call in a while loop is a bad idea.  Query what you'll need beforehand and loop accordingly.

It *appears* that polymorphism can be your friend here.  If you need to keep the same flow, you can do something like this:

```
interface IWhileLoopContinuable
{
   bool KeepGoing {get;}
   void DoWork();
}
```

Then you can use `TakeWhile` on this enumerable:

```
foreach(var item in queriedAsIWhileLoopContinuable.TakeWhile(c => c.KeepGoing))
{
   item.DoWork();
}
```

**All that being said, you could just query for what you want and work on that.**

Comment: That sounds hacky.. and i don't have a collection.

Comment: @Baboon:  You _could_ have a collection if you'd query your values prior to looping...  You'd also get the performance increase of a single database call.

Comment: The database call is necessary, because each time i loop, the value may have change (the workflow where i work at is done entirely in SQL, (GUI as well *sic*)). The DoWork is mostly a Thread.Sleep()

Comment: If you're waiting for a change in the database, might something here work better for you? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364148/sql-server-database-change-listener-c-sharp)

Comment: @Baboon:  There's a link in this comment thread that may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off you cannot "new" a Func, just like you can't new up any delegate type. You must instead assign an existing named method or function literal (aka anonymous delegate, lambda, etc) to initialize a Func variable.

```
//these won't compile; Func has no constructor
Func<bool> condition = new Func<bool>();

//As Jon Skeet notes, these will compile because of language-provided syntax,
//even though Funcs have no constructor with a delegate parameter.
Func<bool> condition = new Func<bool>(SomeNamedMethodReturnsBool);
Func<bool> condition = new Func<bool>(()=>true);

//and these will compile because you're directly assigning the delegate
Func<bool> condition = SomeNamedMethodReturnsBool;
Func<bool> condition = ()=>true;
```

You actually cannot do what you want in C#; an anonymous delegate must be assigned to a variable or parameter in order to be used. It cannot be used in-place as a "function literal" in the abstract sense.

Even if you could, the utility of such a statement escapes me. The delegate would not be re-instantiated every time (the compiler turns anonymous delegates into named private functions of the containing class, with mashup names), but you're adding a layer onto the call stack just to evaluate a constant expression that could be placed directly into the parenthesis of the while() statement. The main utility of an anonymous delegate would be that you could swap out lambdas at runtime, and in order to do that you MUST have a variable.

Comment: the while (delegate { return true; }()) looks good but it says a method name is expected.

Comment: Yeah, you actually cannot use either of these syntaxes; when defining an anonymous delegate you must assign it to a variable or parameter; it cannot be used as an in-place "function literal".

Comment: And +1 for reminding that the delegate wouldn't be reinstantiated every time.

Comment: -1: This is incorrect - the last two of your supposedly invalid lines actually *do* compile. It's not calling a constructor, but it's using a delegate creation expression. See my answer for an example of how it *could* be used, even though I think it shouldn't be.