# using the timer in C# for periodic check events?

Tags: c#, timer

Dear brothers I'm a new comer and I am using XML as database and I want to retrieve the method that fetches data to my label control at every 10 seconds using Timer control in C#.

For Instance The method which retrieves the data and The timer control is:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //here how can I run this method at every 10 seconds  
                    ReturnUknowns();
        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You never asked a question. What is going wrong that your 10 second timer is not working?

Comment: your data changes every 10 seconds?

Comment: If you have a timer, and implemented its event, it should just work.

Comment: Guys, the question is in the code. `//here how can I run this method at every 10 seconds  `

Comment: @Loocid - So is the answer `:)`. `ReturnUknowns();` runs the method.

Comment: If you are asking if this is a correct approach. Then - no. All depends on the database you are using, but for example. SQL server has events. Check out this post, there are many suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364148/sql-server-database-change-listener-c-sharp

Comment: Is the problem your timer is not firing? Please show how you set up yout timer and how you associated timer1_Tick with that timer.

Comment: You need a Timer and set the interval on that instance.

Comment: You should use the new `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer` (new to net6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problems with creating a timer. To execute this function every 10 seconds you need to specify the tick period when creating a timer.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000); // 10 seconds in miliseconds
timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
```

and somwhere you need to set

```
timer.Start()

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           //here how can I run this method at every 10 seconds  
           ReturnUknowns();
}
```

Then each 10 seconds the function timer1_Tick() will be called and all the functions specified in it. The timer.Tick may have a different name based on what type of project you are on.

Comment: You should use the new `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer` (new to net6.0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you can test removing comments from 2 second interval and bit makes sense to understand...

```
 public class Timer1
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public static void Main()
        {
            // Normally, the timer is declared at the class level, 
            // so that it stays in scope as long as it is needed. 
            // If the timer is declared in a long-running method,   
            // KeepAlive must be used to prevent the JIT compiler  
            // from allowing aggressive garbage collection to occur  
            // before the method ends. You can experiment with this 
            // by commenting out the class-level declaration and  
            // uncommenting the declaration below; then uncomment 
            // the GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) at the end of the method. 
            //System.Timers.Timer aTimer; 

            // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

            // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
            //aTimer.Interval = 2000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use 
            // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring 
            // before the method ends. 
            //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
        }

        // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
        // raised. 
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use the new `System.Threading.PeriodicTimer` (new to net6.0).